# Can Azure azcopy pull file from on-prem server?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azcopy

I am very new to Azure, so posting this query. I just want to copy a flat file from an on-prem server to Azure BLOB storage daily basis. I thought "azcopy" will be a good solution for this requirement. But challenge is we can not configure "azcopy" utility in that on-prem server and can not schedule any cron job as this sever is owing by our client. So we thought of running "azcopy" utility from one of the Unix VM in Azure cloud and want to pull the file and transfer to Azure BLOB storage.

I am not getting any clear idea from documentation that "azcopy" can work as a pull manner or not.

Can anyone help me to understand whether my approach will work or not   ? and if not then please give me some idea how to do this.

Please see below diagram depicting what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AzCopy is not designed to be used in that way.

If there's any way for you to access the file, that will be up to your customer and you'd have to ask their network security folks how they would expect it to be done. But most customers (or at least all the ones I worked with before joining Microsoft) prefer push not pull models, since the security for push is more standard and easier to set up.